# CNPropertyNotFetchedException App Crashed

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, addressbook

i want to get the all contacts list of phone with their name as well as phone numbers in swift 3.0 and xcode 8.0. 
below is the code

```
func get_all_user_contacts()
{
    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
    if status == .denied || status == .restricted
    {
        presentSettingsActionSheet()
        return
    }

    // open it

    let store = CNContactStore()
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { granted, error in
        guard granted else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presentSettingsActionSheet()
            }
            return
        }

        // get the contacts

        var contacts = [CNContact]()

        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactIdentifierKey as NSString, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
        do
        {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: request)
            { contact, stop in


                contacts.append(contact)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }

        // do something with the contacts array (e.g. print the names)

        let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
        formatter.style = .fullName
        for contact in contacts
        {
            let MobNumVar  = ((contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value)! as CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
            print(MobNumVar)
            print(formatter.string(from: contact) ?? "???")
        }
    }
}
```

when i run this app it crashes and i don't know where i am getting wrong.
anyone can help me out.. it will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is it crashing? What message are you getting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're requesting keys

```
• CNContactIdentifierKey
• CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)
```

…but then you're trying to access `contact.phoneNumber`.

You can only access keys specified in `keysToFetch`, so you need to add `CNContactPhoneNumbersKey` to that array

Comment: yes. u are right. but can u help me out more that how i can add this to an array. ??? some piece of code.. thnx

Comment: it works. i added: CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor

Comment: The crux of this is you need to fetch the properties you're testing in the predicate as well as any other properties you want.